Power apps doesn't get response from power automate
I built a flow, which should return a string to power apps. However, when I am trying to return string, I am getting nothing:(https://i.sstatic.net/fzYLuBB6.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/zWIlC95n.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/LRfVrSTd.png)
Thanks for your help!
I tried to use TEXT() function in Power Apps.
I tried to use string() function in Power Automate.

How are you getting the response in PowerApp? Share the code that calls the flow. Also ensure you have refreshed the flow in PowerApp to ensure it picks up any changes.
